# How to use Tikz to calculate and use successive color values with text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I'd like to use Tikz to algorithmically generate some text that has a color value based on calculations. Take the following, for example:

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 10} {
          \draw (\i, 0) node {\textcolor[gray]{0.5}A};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

This displays a row of "A"s in a gray:

[image]

How do I go about calculating the `0.5` value to, for example, display this set of "A"s in varying levels of gray, such as a black to white gradient? Could I use this same method to calculate arbitrary RGB values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can vary the gray levels, and the following can be used also to general non-gray colors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i*10)}] in {0, 1, ..., 10} {
          \draw (\i, 0) node[text=gray!\j!white] {A};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, another `foreach` solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0, 10, ..., 100} {
          \draw (\j, 0) node[text=blue!\i!red] {A};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can evaluate a variable within the foreach loop itself *(see page 904 of 3.0.1a manual)*.

Here since you want to go from black to white, you can do:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \gradient using 100-\i*10] in {0, 1, ..., 10} {
          \draw (\i, 0) node[text=black!\gradient] {A};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different syntax than what marmot proposed, but with the same effects

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i*10)}] in {0, 1, ..., 10} {
          (\i, 0) node[text=gray!\j!white] {A}
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```